# How to force MS SharePoint URLs to open in Safari when Chrome is set as default browser?

Tags: macos, safari, web-browser, url, microsoft-sharepoint

I like using Chrome on Mac and it is my default browser.  However, Microsoft SharePoint and Chrome don't work well together.

I am wondering if there is a place where I can specify domains to auto open in Safari? Or better yet, have an option on right click menu of URLs to open in Safari?

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

1. Open Automator (usually found in your Applications folder)
2. Go to File > New (or just press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to create a new item
3. Choose "Service" (it's the one that looks like a cog)
4. Select options based on the picture below

   Note: To get the "Run Shell Script" part, just drag that option from the list on the left pane.
5. Save the service

Now the Service name will show up when you right click on a link, giving you the option to open URLs in safari.

[image: This worked for me]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share how you resolved this! :) If possible, it'd be good if you could expand on your answer a little for those users who aren't familiar with Automator.

Comment: Sure... no prob.  I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for that! :) I hope you don't mind, but I've just reformatted your answer so that it's easier to read.